# Unsigned division in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm, integer-division

I have been trying to debug a little assembly program where I ask for a dividend and a divisor and have to output the quotient and the remainder.  For some reason however, my quotient and remainder are not output to the screen.  Here is my code:

```
segment .data

prompt db "Please enter a number: ", 10
promptLen equ $-prompt
prompt2 db "Please enter the divisor: ", 10
prompt2Len equ $-prompt2
prompt3 db "Your quotient is: ", 10
prompt3Len equ $-prompt3
prompt4 db "Your remainder is: ", 10
prompt4Len equ $-prompt4

segment .bss

inputNum resb 2
inputDiv resb 2
quotient resb 2
remainder resb 2

segment .text

global _start

_start:

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, prompt
mov edx, promptLen
int 80h

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, inputNum
mov edx, 2
int 80h

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, prompt2
mov edx, prompt2Len
int 80h

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, inputDiv
mov edx, 2
int 80h

xor edx, edx
mov ax, [inputNum]
mov bx, [inputDiv]
sub ax, '0'
sub bx, '0'

div bx

add ax, '0'
add dx, '0'
mov [quotient], ax
mov [remainder], dx

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, prompt3
mov edx, prompt3Len
int 80h

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, [quotient]
mov edx, 2
int 80h

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, prompt4
mov edx, prompt4Len
int 80h

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, [remainder]
mov edx, 2
int 80h
jmp exit

exit:

mov eax, 1
xor ebx, ebx
int 80h
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What data are you entering?

Comment: @paxdiablo, I tested it with my dividend being 5 and the divisor being 2

Comment: @paxdiablo, That worked! thank you!  However using the same data, I get 1 as the quotient and 3 as the remainder. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System call 4 (write) requires a `char *` for its buffer address in `ecx`. With your code:

```
mov eax, 4          ; sys_write
mov ebx, 1          ; standard output
mov ecx, [quotient] ; here, ecx <- your character code
mov edx, 2          ; two bytes (hmmm)
int 80h
```

you are loading `ecx` with the actual *data* that was input, rather than the address of it.

What you need to do is to load `ecx` with the *address* of the character, which will probably just be something like:

```
mov ecx, quotient ; here, ecx <- your character address
```

You may also want to reduce your byte count to one rather than two. The way you're turning integers into characters (adding `'0'`) will only work for one-character numbers anyway so you only want the least significant byte (the one at the lowest memory address for x86).

Ditto for the remainder.

---

As an aside, when you *do* fix that, you still get a funny result. Dividing 5 by 2 gives you a quotient of 1 and a remainder of 3, clearly wrong.

This has to do with how you input the data and load the values into `ax` and `bx`.

Since you're reading *two* bytes for each number, the memory is loaded up with the digit itself `'5'`, or `0x35`, followed by a newline character `0x0a`.

Then, when you load the two-byte *word* into `ax`, it ends up with `0x0a35`.

After subtracting `0x0030` (`'0'`) from each, you end up with `0x0a05` and `0x0a02` which is, in decimal, `2565` and `2562`. When you divide *those* numbers, you do indeed get a quotient of `1` and remainder of `3`.

To fix that, you can simply throw away the `0x0a00` but when loading the value, by changing:

```
xor edx, edx
mov ax, [inputNum]
mov bx, [inputDiv]
sub ax, '0'
sub bx, '0'
```

into:

```
xor edx, edx
mov ax, [inputNum]
mov bx, [inputDiv]
and ax, 0xff          ; add these
and bx, 0xff          ;   two lines.
sub ax, '0'
sub bx, '0'
```

Comment: That worked! thank you! However using the same data, I get 1 as the quotient and 3 as the remainder. Any idea why?

Comment: Any suggestion as to how to do the decimal conversion so that I won't be restricted to only one character numbers?

Comment: @user116317, I've updated the answer as to why you're getting the strange result. As to how to handle more than one digit, that should probably be a different question on SO. You'll get more of a response that way rather than asking in a comment box.